# Diff buffer with disk file -- understanding the output tab/windows

Tags: tabbed-user-interface, vimdiff

I use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/749320/492307), reproduced below:

```
function! s:DiffWithSaved()
  let filetype=&ft
  diffthis
  vnew | r # | normal! 1Gdd
  diffthis
  exe "setlocal bt=nofile bh=wipe nobl noswf ro ft=" . filetype
endfunction
com! DiffSaved call s:DiffWithSaved()
```

to visually diff a buffer I am currently working on with the saved version on disk. Suppose my buffer list contains one file, `file1.cpp` (this is the only file that appears on `:ls`). Suppose I modify this buffer and obtain `file1.cpp+`. `+` here indicates that the buffer contents have diverged from the version saved on disk. On calling `:DiffSaved`, the output of `:DiffSaved` appears on the full screen where the screen is split so (x is the cursor position):

```
________________
 .cpp  | .cpp+  |
       |        |
 x     |        |
_______|________|
```

That is, the file on disk appears on left where the cursor is.

On this new tab(?), if I run `:ls`, I still see only `file.cpp+`. Aren't the two windows of the output of `DiffSaved` also part of the buffer list? Is the output of `DiffSaved` on some temporary space elsewhere? Is it possible to have the output so where the current file's buffer appears on the left so that a `:w` saves the file if I am satisfied with the diff? As of now, to save the buffer, either I have to close this diff tab via `:q` and issue a `:w` on the underlying file buffer. Or else, one has to navigate right to the modified buffer in the diff output tab and write buffer to file.

```
Preferred diff output layout
________________
 .cpp+ | .cpp   |
       |        |
 x     |        |
_______|________|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've asked for it (tm). `set nobl` implies that buffer will NOT be shown in `:ls` output. See `:h 'buflisted'`, `:h :ls`. Do not copy/paste so blindly.
2. By default vertical splits are opened with respect to `:h 'splitright'` option (defaults to unset). Either `set splitright` globally or overwrite it for a particular command with `:h :rightbelow` modifier.
3. `vnew` et al. always obtain focus. If you don't do anything to go back (e.g. `wincmd p`) you'll stuck in the newly created window.